# Problems with manually adding constraints, "Simultaneous satisfaction"

Tags: ios

I've been using auto-layout throughout my application, and using the interface builder for all of it up until this point, because I needed a piece of my interface to dynamically change depending on certain aspects, meaning I would have to modify the values of the constraints, and add/remove elements to the view.

I'm aware of what the error, "unable to satisfy constraints simultaneously" means, but I don't see what the problem is. Also, the code that's provided displaying the error looks like a foreign language to me, I don't even understand which constraints are conflicting. I'm only adding 4 constraints

- CenterX
- Top
- Width
- Height

adding these through the interface builder don't cause a problem, so I'm slightly confused as to what the issue is here, so here's my code:

```
func setupProfilePicture() {

        profilePictureView = UIImageView()
        profilePictureView.layer.cornerRadius = profilePictureView.bounds.width / 2
        profilePictureView.clipsToBounds = true
        profilePictureView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        profilePictureView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        profilePictureView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill

        profileConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]();

        // HORIZONTAL CENTER
        profileConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: profilePictureView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
        )
        // FROM TOP
        profileConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: profilePictureView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
        )
        // WIDTH
        profileConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: profilePictureView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 150)
        )
        // HEIGHT
        profileConstraints.append(
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: profilePictureView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 150)
        )


        view.addSubview(profilePictureView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(profileConstraints);

    }
```

Here's the error that I'm receiving:

```
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7ff718dc9b70 h=--& v=--& UIImageView:0x7ff718e9f170.midY ==>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7ff718dc9bc0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIImageView:0x7ff718e9f170(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff718e9f7e0 V:|-(100)-[UIImageView:0x7ff718e9f170]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff718dc0840 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7ff718dca490 h=-&- v=-&- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7ff718dc0840]   (Names: '|':_UIParallaxDimmingView:0x7ff718dbe050 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff718e9f7e0 V:|-(100)-[UIImageView:0x7ff718e9f170]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff718dc0840 )>
```

Comment: Just a guess - try adding `profilePictureView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`? Seems like the auto resizing mask is interfering with the constraints you're adding.

Comment: @DMan - This allowed the image to appear, however it removed any clipping created by the `cornerRadius` value, which hurts, considering the image is supposed to be a circle. Any ideas? EDIT: Also, the image (PNG) that had a transparent background, displays as WHITE instead of transparent.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/GwceTsG.png?1

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it by moving my corner radius code into viewDidLoad - Granted there's a small delay there, it wont work on viewWillLoad.